# SharePoint 2013 sharepoint hosted app step by step

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

how to create a SharePoint hosted app in SharePoint 2013 and share me link which is having step by step approach to understand easily.Also share me the link using NAPA tool to create a SP hosted app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NAPA  is a tool that you can use to create SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-ins. Napa is itself implemented as a (provider-hosted) SharePoint Add-in that can be installed on SharePoint Online websites that are created with the Developer Site template. SharePoint developer sites have a library called Add-ins in Testing on the home page. Instructions for creating a developer site and installing Napa are later in this article.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220041.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/how-to-retrieve-all-users-from-the-group-in-sharepoint-using/

Answer (score 0):

SHA app will create via two option

1. Napa Tools
2. Visual Studio.

Before Start Developing SHA , you need to created and configure Developer site. SHA will create and build app into Developer site. Napa tools will use for small project .

When Your app will work fine . Just upload app into app store and share to everyone or required user .

```
SHA - Sharepoint hosted APP 

JSOM + Oauth + Odata 

Rest API+Oauth + Odata .
```

Please refer below link for SHA help .
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/04/30/sharepoint-hosted-app-visual-studio.aspx